# Move keyboard above TabViewController TabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Is it possible to move the keyboard up so it doesn't cover the UITabViewController's TabBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update after being given more context in comments

If your main concern is letting the user dismiss the keyboard, there are some well known patterns that are commonly applied on the platform:

Assumption regarding UI *(derived from your comment)*:
- `UITableView` as main content

To make the keyboard dismissible, you can utilise a property on `UIScrollView` called `.keyboardDismissMode`. (`UITableView` is derived from `UIScrollView`, so it inherits the property.)

The default value for this property is `.none`. Change that to either `.onDrag` or `.interactive`. Consult the documentation for differences between the latter two options.
Behind the scenes, `UIKit` sets up a connection between the `UIScrollView` instance and any incoming keyboard. This allows the user to "swipe away" the keyboard by interacting with the scroll view.

Note that in order for this feature to work, your `UIScrollView` needs to be scrollable. To understand what 'scrollable' means in this context, please [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/ImJCabus/83568f9b0b14b9c76b04425c6589e858).

If your tableView has very few or no rows, it is likely not natively scrollable. To account for that, set `tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`. This will make sure your users can dismiss the keyboard regardless of the number of rows in the table.

Most of the popular apps handling keyboard dismissal also make it possible to dismiss the keyboard simply by tapping the content partially overlapped by it (in your case, the tableView). To enable this, you would simply have to install a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your view and dismiss the keyboard in its action method:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
  }
}

//MARK: - Tap handling
fileprivate extension MyViewController {
  @objc func handleTap() {
    if searchBar.isFirstResponder {
      searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    // Alternative
    // view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
// -
```

---

### Old answer

Yes, you can actually do this without using private API.
**Disclaimer**

You should really think about whether you actually want to do this. Opening the keyboard in virtually every use case should create a new "context" of editing which modally "blocks" other contexts (such as the navigation context provided by `UITabBarController` and its `UITabBar`). I guess one could make the point that users are able to leave an editing context by interacting with a potentially present `UINavigationBar` which is usually *not* blocked by keyboards. However, this is a known interaction throughout the system. *Not* blocking a `UITabBar` or `UIToolbar` while showing the keyboard on the other hand, is *not*. That being said, use the code below to move the keyboard up, but critically review the UX you are creating. I'm not to say it does *never* make sense to move the keyboard up, but you should really know what you're doing here. To be honest, it also looks kind of iffy, having the keyboard float above the tab bar.

**Code**

```
extension Sequence {
  func last(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
    return try reversed().first(where: predicate)
  }
}

// Using `UIViewController` as an example. You could and actually should factor this logic out.
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
  }

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
  }
}

//MARK: - Keyboard handling
extension MyViewController {
  private var keyboardOffset: CGFloat {
    // Using a fixed value of `49` here, since that's what `UITabBar`s height usually is.
    // You should probably use something like `-tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height`.
    return -49
  }

  private var keyboardWindowPredicate: (UIWindow) -> Bool {
    return { $0.windowLevel > UIWindowLevelNormal }
  }

  private var keyboardWindow: UIWindow? {
    return UIApplication.shared.windows.last(where: keyboardWindowPredicate)
  }

  @objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardWindow = keyboardWindow {
      keyboardWindow.frame.origin.y = keyboardOffset
    }
  }

  @objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardWindow = keyboardWindow {
      keyboardWindow.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
  }
}
// -
```

**Caution**

Note that if you are using the `.UIKeyboardWillShow` and `.UIKeyboardWillHide` notifications to account for the keyboard in your view (setting `UIScrollView` insets, for example), you would have to also account for any additional offset by which you move keyboard window.

This works and is tested with iOS 11. However, there is no guarantee that the UIKit team won't change the order of windows or something else that breaks this in future releases. Again, you are not using any private API, so AppStore review should not be in danger, but you *are* doing something that you're not really supposed to do with the framework, and that can always come around and bite you later on.

Comment: To give some context: I'm writing an app for the visually impaired. One tab has a textfield for entering a search string for fetching publications from a dedicated server. Results are shown in the tableview below the searchfield. How is the user supposed to get out of the search view if there are no results in the table view and the keyboard is covering the tabbar? Another option to moving the keyboard would be moving the tabbar above the keyboard. I just thought keeping the tabbar always at the bottom would have been more consistent.

Comment: In that case, its very easy to apply a well known pattern for iOS. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm using the code above to show my keyboard above the tab bar. However, when slowly swiping back in a navigation controller the tab bar appears twice. Any idea why that happens?